# Run the connectedAndroidTest task does not generate test result xml file anymore

Tags: android, gradle, testing

Maybe from gradle update to version 8.1.0 our command to run ui android tests

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

does not generate test result xml file in the folder

`path_to_your_project/module_name/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/`

as described in the official docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line

It is a bug? Maybe another folder is used to store xml test result?

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to check in the `debug` folder in connected.